# Clase DependencyProperty no encontrada en System.Windows

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy tratando de incluir la clase [DependencyProperty](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyproperty?view=netframework-4.7.2) que se debería encontrar en `System.Windows`.

El problema es que `VisualStudio` no la encuentra.

```
...
using System.Windows;
....

namespace POSViewModels.ViewModels
{
  public class ComprobanteViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    ...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ... <---- Error
    ...
  }
}
```

El error es El nombre del tipo o del espacio de nombres `'DependencyProperty'` no se encontró (¿falta una directiva using o una referencia del ensamblado?).

El ensamblado lo incluí en las referencias del proyecto:

1. Clic derecho en el proyecto.
2. Agregar referencia.
3. Clic en "Ensamblados".
4. Seleccionar `System.Windows`.
5. Clic en "Aceptar".

¿Por qué el `IDE` no detecta la clase cuando el ensamblado se encuentra referenciado y el proyecto configurado para compilar con `.net FrameWork 4.5`?

P/D: uso `VisualStudio 2019 Community`.

Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

mi error fue confundirme entre el espacio de nombres y el ensamblado.

La documentación dice:

- namespace: System.Windows
- Assembly: WindowsBase.dll

Por lo tanto tengo que agregar la referencia a WindowsBase y en el código utilizar el espacio de nombres System.Windows